# Finding IP of Network Switch

Tags: networking, ip

I bought a used Dell PowerConnect 3324 network switch and am trying to connect to it so I can configure it.  I have been using as is for a long while not and it works fine but now it the time to get in an look to see how things work.  Problem is I don't know the IP that is configured with and thus cannot log in.  I have connected directly to the switch using a network cable and ran WireShark but still it is not evident to me.  I am not a network admin so I am not schooled in all the tools to use so if this is too easy than please be kind :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use a serial cable to connect to the console on the switch. From there, type enable to go to privileged mode and then "show running-config" to display the current configuration, including the configured management IP.

Comment: i have the serial also connected but am not familiar with the exact steps you mentioned.  Can you elaborate or reference some specific URL that describes what you are talking about?   Thanks for reading.

Comment: this will get you started http://support.dell.com/support/systemsinfo/document.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&~file=/network/pc33xx/en/ug/installi.htm

Comment: I am using this manual from Dell but it has nothing to say about finding the IP of the machine on the network which does not have the default IP.  Thus we circle back again to the original question.  How do you find the IP of he machine on the network?

Comment: It may not have one, have you been able to display the running configuration?

Answer (score 5):

Attach a single computer to the switch. Configure the computer to use any old IP, with a 0.0.0.0 netmask. Ping 255.255.255.255 and see what IP(s) you get a response from?

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach a serial cable to the console port then use something like Hyperterminal (Windows), and attach to the COM port your serial is plugged into on your PC, to configure it.  Use the commands Spaceman mentioned to get the running config.. However, I can't imagine buying a used switch and just throwing it into production without configuring it.

Comment: Putty is much much better than Hyperterminal.

Comment: I found that using Putty and connecting using the Serial option allows me to use command line interface described in the manual.